# new cohomology of Spec Z?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the "covering" of Spec $\Bbb Z$ by Spec $\Bbb Z_p$ for primes $p$ ($\Bbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers). The intersections of Spec $\Bbb Z_p$ and Spec $\Bbb Z_q$ are defined as fibered products Spec $\Bbb Z_p\otimes\Bbb Z_q$. This space is expected to have a huge number of connected components. Similarly one defines triple intersections, etc. Consider the Cech complex of the constant sheaf with fiber, say, $\Bbb C$ on this covering. What is the cohomology of this complex? Is it something already known? Similar question can be posed for any scheme. One can also incorporate Archimedean points, considering Spec $\Bbb R$ together with Spec $\Bbb Q_p$ as a "covering" of Spec $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I think you have an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes \mathbb{Z}_q \cong \mathbb{Q}_p \otimes \mathbb{Q}_q$, because the tensor product makes $p$ and $q$ invertible.  Your intersections are therefore given by disjoint unions of points.  You may be able to parametrize them by base-changing to separable closures and choosing embeddings $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p) \to Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: I don't think $\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb Q_p \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q_q)$ is a discrete space, or even T$_1$ (like $\operatorname{Spec} \prod_{i=1}^\infty k$). Already things like $k(t) \otimes_k k(t)$ (which is a localisation of $k[x,y]$) have non-closed points.